# ReactJS show loader on child component update

Tags: reactjs

I have seen a lot loader plugins that work for the Mount life cycle but none for the update part and I wonder how to handle it?

What I tried was following setup for parent:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {loader_wrap:false};
      this.hideLoader = this.hideLoader.bind(this);
      this.showLoader = this.showLoader.bind(this);
  }

hideLoader(){
  this.setState({loader_wrap: false});
}

showLoader() {
  this.setState({loader_wrap: true});
}

render() {
  var loaderStyle;
  if (this.state.loader_wrap) {
    loaderStyle = {display:"block"};
  } else {
      loaderStyle = {display:"none"};
  }

return (
        <div>
         <div id="content">
             {React.cloneElement(content, {
                 hideLoader: this.hideLoader,
                 showLoader: this.showLoader
              })}
         </div>
            <div id="loader-wrap" style={loaderStyle}>
                <img className="loader hidden-sm hidden-xs" src='source/file/'>
            </div>
        </div>
)
}
}
```

And this is the child calling the methods:

```
class Childextends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {results:[]};
    this.calculate = this.calculate.bind(this);
}

calculate(dict) {
        this.props.showLoader();

        Actions.action(dict)
          .then(results => {
             this.setState({results: results});
          })
          .catch((err) => {
              var errResp = JSON.parse(err.response);
              console.log(errResp);
              this.setState({responseErrors: errResp});
        });
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.hideLoader();
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.props.hideLoader();
}

componentWillReceiveProps(values){
   this.setState({results:values.results});
}

render() {
        return (
           /*stuff to be returned*/
        )
}
}
```

I also tried to use the Will methods .. which worked even worser :D 
Any ideas how to implement this? I use react with flux but don't now how to use it in this case ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just call hideLoader() in the callback of the action's promise?

```
class Childextends React.Component {

    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {results:[]};
    this.calculate = this.calculate.bind(this);
}

calculate(dict) {
    this.props.showLoader();

    Actions.action(dict)
      .then(results => {
         this.setState({results: results});
      })
      .catch((err) => {
          var errResp = JSON.parse(err.response);
          console.log(errResp);
          this.setState({responseErrors: errResp});
      })
      .then(() => {            
         this.props.hideLoader();
      });

}

render() {
    return (
       /*stuff to be returned*/
    )
  }
}
```

Edit: A different approach to the parent component as well - rather than hiding the element with a style, just don't render it if it isn't required.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
     <div id="content">
         {React.cloneElement(content, {
             hideLoader: this.hideLoader,
             showLoader: this.showLoader
          })}
     </div>

     {this.state.loader_wrap &&
        <div id="loader-wrap" style={loaderStyle}>
            <img className="loader hidden-sm hidden-xs" src='source/file/'>
        </div>
     }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Good point. But it still doesn't work. What is weird is that when I also used a text variable and chaged its value based in hide/showLoader. I could see the text changing but not the styles ... This behaviour is present with my and your version.
EDIT: The loader stays always hidden, never gets visible.

Comment: I tried similar before, but I have a felling this doesn't work because state doesn't rerender immediately when asked to, instead it promises to rerender and does so later. Don't know, just it seems to me I read something like that .. So, in that logic, if I setState loade visible in calculation function. JS moves to the action, that fetches data from server, the sync request sets rerendering on hold and afterwards setState to loader visible together with showing the results. So, the loader never appears? Maybe? He still doesnt. Still thanks for the effort

Comment: It works. There was a error elsewhere, once solved it started to work. Thanks.